# Qt-sdk Setup causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: qt

Immediately after I start the `./qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin` setup and press submit, I get a "Segmentation fault" in the Terminal. What should I do?

Comment: It's something about a segmentation error during setup... but I think english would be better :D

Comment: "sudo ./qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin" , then i'm press next in "Setup" > then "segmentation fault" in Terminal. how to fix? Sorry for my eng =)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to install the "official" Qt SDK in order to do Linux Qt development.  You can install the Qt development libraries (`libqt4-dev`, etc.) and programs (e.g. Qt creator) from within the Ubuntu repositories.  If you're trying to compile your own version specific Qt program available in Ubuntu, you can run `sudo apt-get build-dep [ubuntu package name]` in order to get the libraries that program depends upon.